# #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql

I am trying to insert some data into the table `User`. The `User` table has 2 foreign keys: `StudentID` and `StaffID`.

I want to be able to enter either `StaffID` or `StudentID` which should link to the relevant table(that already has either the `StudentID` or `StaffID`). The table `User` can only have `StaffID` or `StudentID`. Can Anyone help?

```
INSERT INTO `User` (`UserName`, `Email`, `StudentID`,`StaffID`,`Paasword`) 
VALUES ('phill', 'ph@lms.com', '', '2201','654321');
```

Comment: What are the constraints on the User table?  If both StudentID and StaffID are foreign keys and are both required, then you won't be able to leave one or the other null

Comment: That's the thing! The constraints are that the UserID is PK and StaffID and StudentID are FK.

Comment: I do not want both StudentID and StaffID to be required, just one or the other.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so prepare yourself. This answer is long, but thorough.

**Short Answer:**

As referenced in this [answer](/questions/7573590/can-a-foreign-key-be-null-and-or-duplicate#answer-7574042) by [*@HLGEM*](/users/9034/hlgem) you can accomplish what you're asking by making the primary keys in the `STAFF` and `STUDENT` table, presumably the values `StaffID` and `StudentID` *NULLABLE*. Here is the relevant snippet from his answer:

> To allow nulls in an FK generally all you have to do is allow nulls on the field that has the FK. The null value is separate from the idea of it being an FK.

You can do this in your table definition adding `NULL` to your create statement similar to the following by specifying:

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT (
    StudentID INT UNSIGNED NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
    ...
)
```

The above is an example of how to apply this to the `STUDENT` table. The `STAFF` table would have a similar approach. Note, the extra values are there as a suggestion based on general configuration that is common when configuring `ID` fields.

**LONG ANSWER:**

As *@HLGEM* mentioned in his answer, there are some times when it is appropriate to have a foreign key constraint that can be `NULL`. However, in your case, it suggestions that the data is not fully normalized. The need for a `NULL` foreign key can be eliminated in your case with a little table refactoring. Let's explore an additional possibility when designing your database tables:

*Case Study:*

Let's begin with the following assumption. Since you said in your question:

> I want to be able to enter either StaffID or StudentID which should link to the relevant table(that already has either the StudentID or StaffID). The table User can only have StaffID or StudentID

It is probably a safe assumption to say that a user has to be a *staff member* ***or*** a *student* but ***not*** both. That assumption makes a strong use case for having a `UserType` table. Let's alter the `USER` definition to support a `UserTypeId` and create the `USER_TYPE` table:

```sql
# USER TYPE Table Definition
CREATE TABLE USER_TYPES (
  UserTypeId TINYINT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  UserType VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=INNODB CHARSET=UTF8;

# USER TABLE Definition
CREATE TABLE USERS (
  UserId INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  Email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  Password VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  UserTypeId TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY(UserTypeId) REFERENCES USER_TYPES(UserTypeId)
) ENGINE=INNODB CHARSET=UTF8;
```

Notice that in this new schema, we no longer have a reference to `StudentID` or `StaffID`, but instead we have a `UserTypeId`. There are two benefits to this approach:

1. `USERS`.`UserTypeId` is a foreign key reference to `USER_TYPES`.`UserTypeId` but no longer has to be *NULLABLE*.
2. You can have more user types than just `Student` or `Staff`.

For our case study here, let's create two user types `Student` and `Employee` (I'll explain why I'm not using `Staff` here in a little). Let's also go ahead and populate the `USERS` table with the initial values for `Phill`, your employee you mentioned in your question.

```sql
INSERT INTO USER_TYPES(UserType)
VALUES("Employee"),("Student");

INSERT INTO USERS(Name,Email,Password,UserTypeId)
VALUES("phill","ph@lms.com","654321",1);
```

Excellent! Our new design is coming together quickly. Now let's create two additional tables, one called `STUDENTS` and one called `EMPLOYEES`. In this case, I chose to go with `EMPLOYEES` instead of `STAFF` because it allows you to be more flexible in how you define an *employee*. As you'll see in the definition, you can further define a user type of `Employee` with an `ENUM` value of either `Faculty`, `Staff` or `Administrative`. Think of this as a subtype of the general type `Employee`. Note that you could also create another join table like we did for `USER_TYPES`, for instance one called `EMPLOYEE_TYPES`. Either method is appropriate. I chose to use an `ENUM` instead of another foreign key to demonstrate an additional concept you could use if you only have a handful of choices.

So on to those last two table definitions:

```sql
# STUDENTS Table Definition
CREATE TABLE STUDENTS(
  StudentId INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY,
  Year ENUM('Freshman','Sophmore','Junior','Senior') NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY(StudentId) REFERENCES USERS(UserId)
) ENGINE=INNODB CHARSET=UTF8;

# EMPLOYEES Table Definition
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEES (
  EmployeeId INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY,
  EmployeeType ENUM('Faculty','Staff','Administrative') NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY(EmployeeId) REFERENCES USERS(UserId)
) ENGINE=INNODB CHARSET=UTF8;
```

Notice that these two tables do not have their own `Id` column, but instead, reference the `Id` from the `USERS` table as a foreign key constraint. This makes sense because you have to be a *user* before you can be a *student* or an *employee*.

Finally, let's add some *employee* data for `Phill`:

```sql
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES(EmployeeId,EmployeeType)
VALUES(1,"Faculty");
```

That was a lot, but now you'll begin to reap the benefits. Everything above was foundational in that it offers a fully normalized approach to your database layout with additional flexibility and without the need for a *NULLABLE* foreign key.

Retrieving data in this instance is easy and we don't even have to know if `Phill` is an *employee* or a *student*. Let's look at an example query:

```sql
SELECT
u.UserId,
u.Name,
u.Email,
ut.UserType,
s.*,
e.*
FROM USERS AS u
INNER JOIN USER_TYPES AS ut ON u.UserTypeId = ut.UserTypeId
LEFT JOIN STUDENTS AS s ON u.UserId = s.StudentId
LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEES AS e ON u.UserId = e.EmployeeId
WHERE u.Email = "ph@lms.com";
```

which returns:

```
+--------+--------+-------------+-----------+-----------+--------+------------+--------------+
| UserId | Name   | Email       | UserType  | StudentId | Year   | EmployeeId | EmployeeType |
+--------+--------+-------------+-----------+-----------+--------+------------+--------------+
|      1 | phill  | ph@lms.com  | Employee  | (null)    | (null) |          1 | Faculty      |
+--------+--------+-------------+-----------+-----------+--------+------------+--------------+
```

**Conclusion:**

Live Example: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1fcc3/2)

So there you have it. By performing a `LEFT JOIN` between `STUDENTS`, `EMPLOYEES` and the `USERS` table, you'll pull back all values that exist in either of the two tables and all the default user values. From here, it's a simple as checking for `NULL` on `StudentId` or `EmployeeId` to determine which user type you're working with.

Comment: Thank you so much @War10ck!! This is an excellent response. I was able to explore the fundamentals easily. :)